# "Jump to definition" for methods without external parameter names

Tags: xcode, swift

For method calls *with external parameter names* I can <kbd>cmd</kbd>-click in Xcode on any parameter name to jump to the method definition. For
example, in

```
let a = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)
```

a <kbd>cmd</kbd>-click on "count" or "repeatedValue" jumps directly to the `Array` initializer method

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: Element)
```

However, I haven't found a way to do the same for methods calls
*without external parameter names*, as in

```
let c = Array("abc".characters)
```

Of course I can lookup that the `characters` method returns a `String.CharacterView` which in turn conforms to `SequenceType`, so this will call the `Array` initializer

```
init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == _Buffer.Element>(_ s: S)
```

but I wonder if somebody has found a *direct "jump to definition" method*
for this situation.

This would be very useful if a type has many overloaded init methods (without external parameter names), to determine which one is actually called.

The above examples are from Swift 2/Xcode 7 beta, but the problem is not
tied to a special Swift/Xcode version.

(Also posted at the Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12687.)

Comment: Can you not click on "Array"?  I've never even thought to click on the parameters names and always clicked on the part outside the parens.  (I guess in this case, it just goes to the class declaration and not the specific initializer.)

Comment: @nhgrif: Exactly, cmd-click on "Array" jumps to `public struct Array<Element> : ...`, that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do some work:

```
let c = Array.init("abc".characters)
//           ^^^^^
```

Use [initializer expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID399), then <kbd>cmd</kbd> + click on it.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Works with Swift 1.2 and 2.0. – (Why didn't I think of that ? :)