# Can't find the "Int" type initialiser that takes a string as argument in Apple's Swift official documentation

Tags: ios, swift, int

I'm new to Swift. I saw this code online:

```
let number = Int("123")
```

I want to read a bit more about the "Int" type initialiser that take a string as a argument. However, when I looked at Apple's offical Swift documentations:

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Int_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Si

I couldn't find a Int type initialiser that actually takes a string as its argument. Am I looking at the wrong place? Or is there something I'm missing or unaware of?

[image]

Comment: Only after answering the question I noticed that I had answered the same question some time ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on [`init(_:radix:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Int_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Int/s:FSicFMSiFTSS5radixSi_GSqSi_) to expand the declaration then you'll see

> Construct from an ASCII representation in the given radix.
>
> Declaration
> `init?(_ text: String, radix radix: Int = default)`

The first parameter is a string (and has an empty external parameter
name). The second parameter "radix" has a *default value*,
therefore it can be omitted when calling the function:

```
let number = Int("123")
```

but you can specify the radix to create a number from a string
representation in another base:

```
let numberFromHexString = Int("100", radix: 16) // Optional(256)
let numberFomOctalString = Int("077", radix: 8) // Optional(63)
```

There is also a "trick" which I learned at
["Jump to definition" for methods without external parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048978/jump-to-definition-for-methods-without-external-parameter-names): If you write

```
let number = Int("123")
```

as

```
let number = Int.init("123")
```

then you can "command-click" on "init" in Xcode, and you are led
directly to the declaration

```
public init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That make everything much clearer! really appreciate your help!