# Two init functions with UIColor ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicolor

I was applying colors to the label and found out that we have two functions doing the same thing.
Can anyone explain me what is need of these two functions, why can't we have only one function?

Normally used:

```
public init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
```

Seen it when i went to UIColor class:

```
required public convenience init(colorLiteralRed red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float)
```

Are there advantages or disadvantages with the two functions?

Also, what is the best way to call:

1. `footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1)`
2. `footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1)`
3. `footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convenience initializer is used for color literals (as the argument label says). You can see it in both Xcode and in Playgrounds when you drag and drop a color.

I don't see any reason to call the color literal initializer yourself. Instead you'd most likely use either Option 1 or perhaps `UIColor(displayP3Red:green:blue:alpha:)` if you wanted to use the Display P3 color space.

Comment: Here https://medium.com/@gurdeep060289/color-image-new-literals-in-the-cocoa-town-7ef4f2710194#.fkq9irrry is a demonstration of the color literals, and here https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0039-playgroundliterals.md the corresponding proposal.

Comment: @MartinR I meant to refer to the unit method, but I can see  how it looks like I'm suggesting using `.init(` at the call site . (Now edited)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist One more thing ... calling uicolor.init vs uicolor .. are there some disadvantages ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta as far as I know it's only a choice of style. There are cases when it's convenient to reference the initializer as a function without calling it. Other than that I mostly see `SomeType( ... )`.

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta: It makes no difference, but the `SomeType.init(...)` allows you to "jump to the definition" even for constructors without external parameters, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048978/jump-to-definition-for-methods-without-external-parameter-names.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a `UIColor` extension which is adding the `UIColor(colorLiteralRed:, green:, blue:, alpha:)` init method.  The standard `UIKit` method is the first method.  Perhaps colorLiteralRed just takes 178, 178, 178, rather than 178/255, 178/255, 178/255?  **This is wrong**

### Edit

You are correct - my guess is that `colorLiteralRed` is to support the new `Color Literal` syntax in Xcode. Try typing this in Xcode - `let color:UIColor = Color Literal` and let the autocomplete pop up a color picker.  If you select a color there will be a square of color in Xcode. However, the source code looks like `let color = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)`.  While it's not documented, my guess is the method you are referencing is called here.

Comment: No this is Apple's method in UIColor. This is present in standard UIKit

Answer (score 0):

First Method

`init(colorLiteralRed:green:blue:alpha:)` is intended to be used with Color Literals which are managed by development tools.

Second Method

`init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)` is intended to be used by iOS apps to create color.

Both are equivalent in terms of performance. We should not use `init(colorLiteralRed:green:blue:alpha:)` because in Swift4 apple has deprecated this method.