# Is there difference between using a constructor and using .init?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Fruit {
    var fruitName: String

    init(getFruit name: String) {
        fruitName = name
    }

}
```

Is there any difference between using the constructor, and using .init?

```
var apple = Fruit(getFruit: "apple")
var orange = Fruit.init(getFruit: "orange")
```

Im not seeing any difference in playground.
[image]

I apologize if the question is badly worded or has been asked before.

Comment: Both are calls to the initializer as there are no constructors in Swift, only initializers and it's just syntactic sugar that you can omit the explicit `.init` call.

Comment: It makes a tiny difference in the Xcode editor: With the `SomeType.init(...)` syntax you can always “jump to definition,” even if the init method has no external parameter names (https://stackoverflow.com/q/32048978/1187415). That's why I use it sometimes *temporarily* to find out which init method (from multiple overloads) is actually used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Initializer Expression section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID399):

> If you specify a type by name, you can access the type’s initializer without using an initializer expression. In all other cases, you must use an initializer expression.
>
> let s1 = SomeType.init(data: 3)  // Valid
>   let s2 = SomeType(data: 1)       // Also valid
>
> let s3 = type(of: someValue).init(data: 7)  // Valid
>   let s4 = type(of: someValue)(data: 5)       // Error

Initializing using the explicit `.init` on the type directly is no different than without it; they are equivalent from Swift's perspective, so most folks prefer the brevity of omitting `.init`.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is absolutely no difference.

It is generally convention in Swift to call the constructor without the `.init` This is the 'swiftier' shorthand.