# Difference between using class() and class.init() in swift

Tags: swift

Why we need to use init method explicitly while we can create an object without it

```
class Details {

}

var obj = Details()
var obj = Details.init()
```

What's the difference between these two instance creations

Comment: It's just different ways of doing the same thing. Choose which is convenient for you. The new `Class()` or the old `Class.init()` which is Objective-C like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are allowed and are equivalent. As [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID397) says:

> If you specify a type by name, you can access the type’s initializer without using an initializer expression. In all other cases, you must use an initializer expression.
>
> ```
> let s1 = SomeType.init(data: 3)  // Valid
> let s2 = SomeType(data: 1)       // Also valid
>
> let s3 = type(of: someValue).init(data: 7)  // Valid
> let s4 = type(of: someValue)(data: 5)       // Error
> ```

So, when you’re supplying the name of the type when instantiating it, you can either use the `SomeType(data: 3)` syntax or `SomeType.init(data: 3)`. Most Swift developers would favor `SomeType(data: 3)` as we generally favor brevity unless the more verbose syntax lends greater clarity, which it doesn’t in this case. That having been said, `SomeType.init(data: 3)` is permitted, though it is less common in practice.

Comment: It makes a tiny difference in the Xcode editor: With the `SomeType.init(...)` syntax you can always “jump to definition,” even if the init method has no external parameter names (https://stackoverflow.com/q/32048978/1187415). That's why I use it sometimes *temporarily* to find out which init method (from multiple overloads) is actually used.

Answer (score 2):

`Class()` is just a shorthand for `Class.init()`

Both are interpreted by the compiler as exactly the same statements with no difference at all.